# if else doesnt work-who want to be miliondolare nodeJS

Tags: node.js, discord.js

the if else doesnt work with me

```
            const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return ['', '', '', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot;}
                message.awaitReactions(filter, {max: 1, time: 20000, errors: ["time", "max"]})
                .then(collected => {
                    console.log(random_question.correct)
                    var reaction = collected.first().emoji.name
                    console.log(reaction)
                    if (reaction == '') {
                        if(random_question.correct == "0")
                          return  message.channel.send("bạn vừa trả lời đúng rồi đấy")
                           else message.channel.send(`bạn vừa trả lời sai`)
                        }
                   else if (reaction == 'B') {
                    if(random_question.correct == "1")
                      return  message.channel.send("bạn vừa trả lời đúng rồi đấy")
                       else message.channel.send(`bạn vừa trả lời sai`)
                    }
                   else if (reaction == 'C') {
                    if(random_question.correct == "2")
                      return  message.channel.send("bạn vừa trả lời đúng rồi đấy")
                       else message.channel.send(`bạn vừa trả lời sai`)
                    }
                   else if (reaction == 'D') {
                    if(random_question.correct == "3")
                      return  message.channel.send("bạn vừa trả lời đúng rồi đấy")
                       else message.channel.send(`bạn vừa trả lời sai`)
                    }
                })
                .catch (errors => {
                    message.channel.send(` hết giờ! `);
                });
            })
```

this is output in console:

```
{
  correct: 0,
  content: [ 'Orissa', 'Tamil nadu', 'Andhra Pradesh', 'Kerala' ],
  question: 'Heavy Water Project (Talcher) and Fertilizer plant (Paradeep) are famous industries of'
}
```

when i choose "A" it will respond correctly but when i choose B, C, D i can't get the respond
can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have any conditional statements (or anything else) after the `return` keyword - put the code like this:

```
    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return ['', '', '', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && !user.bot;}
        message.awaitReactions(filter, {max: 1, time: 20000, errors: ["time", "max"]})
        .then(collected => {
            console.log(random_question.correct)
            var reaction = collected.first().emoji.name
            console.log(reaction)
            if (reaction == '') {
                if(random_question.correct == "0")
                  return  message.channel.send("bạn vừa trả lời đúng rồi đấy")
                   
                } else {
message.channel.send(`bạn vừa trả lời sai`)
}
           else if (reaction == 'B') {
            if(random_question.correct == "1")
              return  message.channel.send("bạn vừa trả lời đúng rồi đấy")
               
            } else {
message.channel.send(`bạn vừa trả lời sai`)
}
           else if (reaction == 'C') {
            if(random_question.correct == "2")
              return  message.channel.send("bạn vừa trả lời đúng rồi đấy")
               
            } else {
message.channel.send(`bạn vừa trả lời sai`)}
           else if (reaction == 'D') {
            if(random_question.correct == "3")
              return  message.channel.send("bạn vừa trả lời đúng rồi đấy")
              
            } else {
message.channel.send(`bạn vừa trả lời sai`)
}
        })
        .catch (errors => {
            message.channel.send(` hết giờ! `);
        });
    })
```

(Sorry about bad indentation)

Explanation: return makes the code after it not run. Also, the else statement has to be after the end of the if statement.